# Публикация в группу на "Одноклассниках"

Tags: curl, php

Всем привет! Ребята, может кто-то сталкивался с публикацией новостей (текст+картинка) на Одноклассниках со стороннего сайта? Интересует сам механизм. Гуглить пробовал- не помогло. Понял только, что через `cUrl` можно. Но ничего толком не разъясняется. Буду рад любой помощи . Спасибо всем, кто неравнодушен =)

P.S.: Если есть какие-либо наработки и если не жалко, то поделитесь, плиз =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Слишком много возникает сложностей при написании приложения для одноклассников, особенно для программистов-одиночек (имхо). Я бы рекомендовал смотреть в сторону сервисов кросспостинга из `rss`-канала, к примеру [`RSSTranslator`](http://beta.rsstranslator.net/). Сам им не пользовался и привожу только для примера.

Comment: Вопрос не об этом

Comment: > Буду рад любой помощи
Я думал это не вопрос, а просьба о помощи...